# Grep output only the regex matches

Tags: regex, grep

Not very good with regex let alone regex inside grep but I'm close to what I need. I have this mouse that I want to extract it's ids (it has 2 ids printed as pointer and one as keyboard) and I can't make grep to only print the id numbers for pointer values.

The input text is as follows:

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06E4:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910             id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logitech G633 Gaming Headset     id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910             id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

The way I got close is using this command:

`xinput --list --short | grep -oP 'Razer.*id=\K([0-9]+)(.*?)pointer'`

but this prints:

`20   [slave  pointer
21  [slave  pointer`

How can I make it only print `20` and `21`? `pointer` is needed because I only want the ids of pointers.

Comment: If you have a hard time with regex, maybe `xinput --list --short | grep -i razer | cut -d= f2 | cut -d" " -f1` is more straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead in your regex to assert presence of `pointer` after your `id` numbers without actually matching it:

```
xinput --list --short | grep -oP 'Razer.*id=\K(\d+)(?=.*pointer)' file
```

**Output:**

```
20
21
```